# Como converter um inteiro para uma string binária no Python 3?

Tags: string, python-3.x

Se eu quero converter entre inteiros e caracteres, uso [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) e [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> chr(10)
'\n'
>>> ord('$')
36
```

Entretanto eu preciso fazer um teste com strings **binárias**, algo novo no Python 3, e eu - que só tenho experiência com o Python 2 - não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer:

```
# O que eu sei
teste(b'\x00')
teste(b'\x01')
teste(b'\x02')
...
teste(b'\xff')

# O que eu quero
for i in range(256)
    teste(???)
```

Comment: Acho que você está procurando isso: http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/

Comment: @AndréRamos Esse artigo só fala da conversão entre strings (texto) e bytes através de um *encoding*. O problema são aquelas sequências de bytes que não representam texto nenhum em *qualquer* encoding (ex.: `b"\xdb"` não é uma string válida em nenhuma codificação Unicode). De todo modo, eu quero trabalhar com bytes "crus", não com texto, qualquer conversão desse tipo seria uma "gambiarra".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Stack Overflow em inglês tem [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3).

Então seu loop seria (limitei o máximo, mas teste que funciona):

```
>>> for i in range(20):
...   print(bytes([i]))
... 
b'\x00'
b'\x01'
b'\x02'
b'\x03'
b'\x04'
b'\x05'
b'\x06'
b'\x07'
b'\x08'
b'\t'
b'\n'
b'\x0b'
b'\x0c'
b'\r'
b'\x0e'
b'\x0f'
b'\x10'
b'\x11'
b'\x12'
b'\x13'
```

Não se preocupe com o `b'\t'`, pois são caracteres especiais bem conhecidos.

Comment: Ótimo, valeu! Eu havia dado uma olhada rápida na [documentação do `bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-bytes), mas sem um exemplo não percebi que poderia usá-la desse jeito (com um *iterable* de inteiros).

Comment: Oi, Paulo, comentário temporário e off-topic. Me apareceu [a seguinte edição sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/43937) para aprovar e decidi pular pois não é minha praia. Com sorte, os revisores que decidirem conhecem MongoDB, mas pode ser que rejeitem; seria a reação natural dentro deste eco-sistema. O que sugiro é que você faça sua própria resposta (colocando um sumário daqueles links para sites externos).